# Problem with post in Sinatra

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I'm using JQuery to post in a Sinatra application.

```
  $.post("/addnewlistitem", $('#inputrow1').val(), function(data){alert(data);});
```

Haml looks like this:

```
%input{:type => "text", :id => "inputrow1", :name => "item", :class => "txt"}
```

And the ruby code, like this:

```
post '/addnewlistitem' do
  @v = params[:item]
end
```

The problem is that I can't get the data posted from JQuery. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your jquery post. It should look like this:

```
 $.post("/addnewlistitem", {item: $('#inputrow1').val()}, function(data){alert(data);});
```

Then it should all work. If not, I'll paste in my version of all this that I just tested.